# node-soap force array when reponse field contains one child

Tags: javascript, xml, soap, node-soap

When converting a field in XML in a response using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap), I would like to force a field to be an array even though it contains one child.

When there is only one child, a field is interpreted as an object. Please see an example below:

```
// Below gives {ArrayOfItems: {Item: { name: 'foo', ... }}
// But I'd like it to be {ArrayOfItems: {Item: [{name: 'foo', ... }]}
<ArrayOfItems>
  <Item>
    ...
  </Item>
</ArrayOfItems>

// Below gives  {ArrayOfItems: {Item: [{ name: 'foo', ... }, { name: 'bar', ... }]}
<ArrayOfItems>
  <Item>
    ...
  </Item>
  <Item>
    ...
  </Item>
</ArrayOfItems>
```

How can I force my field to be parsed as an array when converted from xml to object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with both LoopBack Enterprise SOAP connector and node-soap.

The easiest workaround I found was to have a simple method which does the following:

```
function forceArray(array) {
      if (!array || Array.isArray(array))
        return array;
      else
        return [array];
}
```

Does that helps?

Comment: Yes I ended up writing a function to cast something to array. But it seems hacky. Are there other solutions?

Comment: you can modify the code of node-soap to accept a *forceArray* option to perform this for you ... but then - at what level will it force the array? only on the top? for each child of the top objects? it's very application specific